# Find the exact values of $\sec\theta$ and $\cot\theta$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Let $\theta$ be an angle in quadrant IV such that $\sin \theta = −12/13$.

Then, find the exact values of $\sec\theta$ and $\cot\theta$.

---

I've done the Pythagorean theorem: 5 for the adjacent side.

$\sec\theta = -12/5$

$\cot\theta = -5/13$

Is this correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right that 5 would be the adjacent side. So we have a right triangle, where the adjacent side is 5, the opposite side is -12, and the hypotenuse is 13.

$\sec \theta = \frac{1}{\cos \theta}$, so $\sec \theta$ is (hypotenuse)/(adjacent) $=\frac{13}{5}$.

$\cot \theta = \frac{1}{\tan \theta}$, so $\sec \theta$ is (adjacent)/(opposite) $=-\frac{5}{12}$.

---

Alternatively, note that $\sin ^2 \theta + \cos^2 \theta = 1$, so $(-\frac{12}{13})^2 + \cos^2 \theta = 1$, and $\cos \theta = \pm \frac{5}{13}$. Since we're in quadrant IV, we know that $\cos \theta$ is positive, so $\cos \theta = \frac{5}{13}$.

Then $\sec \theta = \frac{1}{\cos \theta} = \frac{13}{5}$.

And $\cot \theta = \frac{1}{\tan \theta} = \frac{\cos \theta}{\sin \theta} = -\frac{5}{12}$.

Answer (score 1):

You have worked out that this is a $5 - 12 - 13$ triangle.  With 5 as the base, 12 as the height and 13 as the hypotenuse.

$\sec \theta = \frac 1{\cos\theta} = \frac {\text{Adjacent}}{\text {Hypotenuse}}$

$\cot \theta = \frac {\cos\theta}{\sin\theta}$

Next question.  What are the signs?  In Q IV.  $\cos \theta > 0, \sin \theta < 0$

What do you think the signs of $\sec\theta, \cot \theta?$

Answer (score 0):

I think you have made mistake with sides.

$\sin \theta = \frac{\text{Perpendicular}}{\text{Hypotenuse}} $

So comparing with values,

Perpendicular = 12 and Hypotenuse = 13

Using phythagorous you got base as 5.

$\cos \theta = \frac{\text{Base}}{\text{Hypotenuse}} $

$\cos \theta = \frac{5}{13}$

As $\cos\theta$ positive as in IV quadrant.

$\cot \theta = \frac{\text{Base}}{\text{Perpendicular}} $

$\cot \theta = \frac{-5}{12}$

As $\cot\theta$ negative as in IV quadrant.